# SwiftUI CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not getting called

Tags: swiftui, core-location

I have the following LocationManager class to fetch the users location to call another method with this. The problem is that the didUpdateLocations Delegate never gets called. The App has the authorization (identifiers are set), location services are enabled and the startUpdatingLocation method is also getting called. I'm calling the fetchLocation method from an onAppear method of a SwiftUI View.
Both simulator (test location is set) and my actual device are running into this.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func fetchLocation() {
    
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(),
       (manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
        
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
    if let location = locations.first {
        
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        
        Weather().fetchWeatherData(location: location)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    
    print(error)
}
```

I'm calling the method as followed

```
var body: some View {
            
    ZStack { ... }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .onAppear {
        
        LocationManager().fetchLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're instantiating/storing LocationManager?

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: You need to store a reference to your LocationManager. It is immediately going out of scope. Read about `@StateObject`

Comment: That's it, thanks. I added the changes as an answer to the question

Comment: It's best to have one StateObject with a location manager for authorisation then when authorised show another View that has a StateObject with a location manager for locations. Then if user disables location in Settings, the location view will be hidden again.

Answer (score 1):

Added `@StateObject var locationManager: LocationManager` to my SwiftUI view to use `locationManager.fetchLocation()`

Also changed my LocationManager from `let manager = CLLocationManager()` to `@Published var manager = CLLocationManager()`, now it's working and the didUpdateLocations method is getting called.

Comment: That `@Published` change shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Dont’t forget to add ObservableObject to the class —- class LocationManager: ObservableObject, NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35159132)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).